# label rotate works in IE but not in in chrome using jquery rotate

Tags: jquery, rotation

I am using plugin http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate3.js for rotating any object in my project. This works fine in IE for label rotate but the same does not work in chrome.?
please any comment with any solution. 
I already tried adding label inside div and rotating div but this way i don't get proper height/width after rotation.

check this - http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2909/

Comment: I see a rotating Google Logo in Chrome. Is this the wanted behavior?

Comment: For me working too. **Chrome 21.x**

Comment: I need height and width of label so i can assign it to parent div. After rotating the label it don't get it's height/width in chrome where it works fine in IE. see the update link jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2930 . will be very thankful if you help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block;` to your `#LogoText1` css. Looks like chrome can't apply `transform:rotate(...)` to inline elements.

```
#LogoText1{
  margin:100px 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2913/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need height and width of label so i can assign it to parent div. After rotating the label it don't get it's height/width in chrome where it works fine in IE. see the update link http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2930/ . will be very thankful if you help on this.

Comment: You need formula like this: `var x = $('#box').width()*Math.cos(rotationAngle) + $('#box').height()*Math.sin(rotationAngle);` to calculate correct widht/height

Comment: Well... that is not completely correct formula, but the only way looks to be apply some math to rotation angle and available widths and heights

Comment: thanks, i got one function which return height/width after rotation. This works fine in IE but not in chorme. any idea? see here http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2944/

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that jQueryRotate3 is in the experilental phase, and that the previous versions were meant for `img` tags only, support for labels might be added later on.

Meanwhile, inline tags are not going to rotate easily. The only solution I have found and used is to change the styles of the label a bit. Try by adding `display:block;position:absolute` to the label style just before rotating it.

Since you are talking about incorrect height and width, use `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` to define the size of the label before you make it `block`. And maybe add a buffer to keep taking the space it was taking by adding a `span` with `display inline-block` and the same sizes you have retreived.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need height and width of label so i can assign it to parent div. After rotating the label it don't get it's height/width in chrome where it works fine in IE. see the update link http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2930/ . will be very thankful if you help on this.

Comment: I have done a little gymnastic to have it display in the middle. http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2947/ Basically, we take the longest between width and height and set both to that then we position the rotating label in the center of the div.

Comment: thanks for this. but i need exact height and width because the div is draggable and i want to give correct height and width to it so user cannot drag it outside the containment.

Comment: What do you mean by exact? It is either the dimensions of the element rotating or the bounderies in which it rotates. You had the first and I present you with the other...

Comment: After rotating element it's height & width changes which i need for calculation of dimensions etc. I have made another example which works fine in IE but not in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2951/ please if you can help on this.

Comment: I see the same thing in IE and Chorme. Only 2px differences in dimensions but that's without reset.css

Comment: in IE (IE 8 version i am using) you can see that Height and Width of a rotating div is changing (http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2951/) but in chrome it doesn't. I need exact height and width as this information is required for customer. In my example i have added setinterval function but in actual user will be rotating the object using slider. So i need get correct angle but i also need changed height and width of the object in chrome.

Comment: Ok, using the width of your label, you could calculate it using angle + hypotenuse (width) mathematics to calculate the total height and width at a given rotation angle. Here are the formulas you'll need: http://easycalculation.com/trigonometry/triangle-angles.php
I found you one that uses javascript so you can easily implement it